# Java SWT GC not drawing text on Canvas

Tags: java, canvas, garbage-collection, swt, drawtext

I have the following code:

```
   final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainshell, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE);

     canvas.setBounds(0, 0, mainshell.getSize().x, mainshell.getSize().y);

     canvas.setBackgroundImage( new Image(display, "BlueBack.jpg" ));
     canvas.setFont(font);

      GC gc = new GC(canvas);

      gc.drawText("Test", 0, 0, true);

      gc.dispose();

        canvas.addPaintListener(new PaintListener() {
            public void paintControl(PaintEvent e) {    

           e.gc.drawText("String", 170, 30, true);

           e.gc.drawText("Another Unimportant String", 80, 90, true);


           int I = 140;
           int i = 1;

         String[] strings = Stuff.getUnimportantStringArray();

         if(strings != null)
           for(String string : strings){

               e.gc.drawText( i + "      " + string , 120, I, true);

               I += 50;
               i++;

           }

            }
        });
```

The code that I am having the problem with is this:

```
 GC gc = new GC(canvas);

      gc.drawText("Test", 0, 0, true);

      gc.dispose();
```

The `gc.drawText();` is not drawing the String `"Test"` on the canvas as I expected it would.

Here is my Question:

Why is the `gc.drawText("Test", 0, 0, true");` not working, but the `e.gc.drawText("String", 170, 30, true);` inside the `PaintListener`is working ?

Comment: First, this has nothing to do with garbage-collection but with the GraphicsContext of SWT. Second, it seems that the text gets overridden by the content drawn by the listener or the background of the canvas in general. Maybe you can try one of the `SWT` flags presented in this [introduction to SWT](http://eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-graphics/SWT_graphics.html#Canvas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `paintControl()` method is called whenever the canvas needs to be redrawn which could happen any number of times. For example, the `PaintListener` is used when the canvas is resized (try putting a breakpoint on `paintControl()`, resize the window, and see for yourself). All drawing you need to do should be in the `PaintListener`.

Also, you shouldn't use `setBounds()` here. Use a layout instead:

```
mainShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
```

Comment: The reason I drew "Test" outside the PaintListener is because I need to be able to remove it from the screen and the best way I know how to do that is to redraw the canvas. Yes, I know I should have used a Layout, but this is part of a larger project in which every widget has their Bounds explicitly coded.

Comment: I think you should still put the drawing code in the `PaintListener`, and work out how to get it to draw what you want in the logic of your code. For example, if what needs to be drawn depends on a boolean value, you can check it from `paintControl()` and draw the appropriate content.

Comment: Also, `setBounds()` is usually used from within a layout. You can write a custom layout by writing a class which extends `Layout`. There's an example towards the end of [this page](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

Comment: I will do that. I knew that it was on option, but I was trying to avoid it. I can't really give a reason why. Thank you for the Link.

Comment: I understand you want to keep unnecessary complexity out of your code, but I don't think there's another way in this case. And no problem, I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used a boolean (as you suggested) to tell whether or not it should draw the String and it worked fine. Thanks.